# How to insert data into SQL Server in a C# ASP.NET website?

Tags: c#

The code in the code behind file (`.aspx.cs`):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=Welcome@123database=login;";
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    try
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into user(userid,username,password) values('" + txtuserid.Text + "','" + txtusername.Text + "','" + txtpassword.Text + "')", con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", txtuserid.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtusername.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpassword.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Response.Write("<script>alert('User Added Successfully')</Script>");       
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('User registration was unsuccessful')</Script>");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to insert data into sql server from my website build in vs 2015.For that I used button click event .I tried code shown in youtube but the code doesn't work .It shows error in my website.

Comment: I tried to insert data into sql server from my website build in vs 2015.For that I used button click event .I tried code shown in youtube but the code doesn't work .Plz correct my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the message in the exception that gets thrown?

Comment: Double check your connection string. You're clearly missing a semi-colon. Also, if the video is advising you to store the password in plaintext, find a different video. Don't develop bad habits.

Comment: There's also the issue of SQL injection. The correct way to pass across the fields is of course SqlParameters, which are already there but not being referenced in the sql statement....

Comment: Plz anybody give me a new correct code.

Comment: We need to know what the problem is (not just "the code is not working"). Run the code in a debugger or log the exception message somehow, that will give you more information and if you still can't solve the problem, post it here.

Answer (score 1):

You've totally misunderstood how parameters are supposed to be used. What you're doing is SQL injection-prone **string concatenation** of SQL statements - **do NOT do this!**

Use this code instead:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into user (userid, username, password) " +
                                "values (@userId, @userName, @password);";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", txtuserid.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", txtusername.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpassword.Text);
```

Comment: The error I recieved was NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code...Object reference not set to an instance of an object